# How to Implement Lazy Loading Translations in i18next with React?

Tags: performance, internationalization, lazy-loading, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using i18next with React and have three language files (Arabic, English, and French). Currently, I'm loading all three translation files when a user requests the site, which feels like too much data to send initially. Although it has the benefit of instant translation when a user switches languages, I'd like to explore the possibility of implementing lazy loading translations to load only one translation file initially and then load the others when the user changes the language, with a simple loading screen.

Here's my i18n.ts file:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import en from '/public/locales/en/translation.json'
import fr from '/public/locales/fr/translation.json'
import ar from '/public/locales/ar/translation.json'

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: en
      },
      fr: {
        translation: fr
      },
      ar: {
        translation: ar
      }
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

And here's my language toggle component:

```
/* eslint-disable no-alert, no-console */
import i18n from "i18next";
import { Globe2 } from "lucide-react";
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { DropdownMenu, DropdownMenuContent, DropdownMenuItem, DropdownMenuTrigger } from "./ui/dropdown-menu";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

interface Language {
  label: string;
  dir: "ltr" | "rtl";
  active: boolean;
}

const lngs: Record<string, Language> = {
  en: { label: "English", dir: "ltr", active: true },
  ar: { label: "العربية", dir: "rtl", active: false },
  fr: { label: "Français", dir: "ltr", active: false },
};


function LanguageToggle({ className }: { className: string }) {
  const storedLanguage = localStorage.getItem("i18nextLng") || "en";
  const selected = Object.keys(lngs).find((lng) => storedLanguage.startsWith(lng)) || "en";
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const [menuAnchor,] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.dir = lngs[selected].dir;
  }, [menuAnchor, selected]);

  return (
    <div className={cn(className)} >

      <DropdownMenu >
        <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild className="cursor-pointer"  >
          <Button style={{ paddingBlock: "19px" }} className="" variant="outline" size="sm">
            <span className="me-2" >{t('language')} </span><Globe2 />
          </Button>
        </DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <DropdownMenuContent align="end">

          {Object.keys(lngs).map((lng) => (
            <DropdownMenuItem className="cursor-pointer" key={lng} onClick={() => {
              i18n.changeLanguage(lng)
            }}>
              {lngs[lng].label}
            </DropdownMenuItem>
          ))}



        </DropdownMenuContent>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </div>
  )


}

export default LanguageToggle
```

Is it possible to implement lazy loading translations in this setup to improve initial loading performance while maintaining a smooth language-switching experience for users? If so, how can I achieve this?

I attempted to implement lazy loading translations in my React application using i18next. What I expected was that initially, only one translation file would be loaded, and when the user changed the language, the corresponding translation file would load with a loading screen, improving the initial loading performance.

In my implementation, I followed the standard i18next setup, as shown in my code. However, I'm unsure about how to achieve the lazy loading of translations as described above. I'm looking for guidance on the best practices or code examples to implement this functionality effectively.

Comment: I believe it is possible to do so, check this link from [i18next documentation](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#lazy-load-in-memory-translations).

Answer (score 2):

Got time to answer this question - I have recently worked on a commercial project that requires the lazy-loading of locale files.

Besides the above link I wrote in the comment section, the below solution also works fine for it (which is also suggested by the `i18next-resources-to-backend` [guidelines](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-resources-to-backend)):

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import ChainedBackend from "i18next-chained-backend";
import HttpBackend from "i18next-http-backend";
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';

i18n
    .use(ChainedBackend)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        lng: 'en', // default language
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        defaultNS: 'translation', // default namespace, if you don't want to specify it in JS files every time.
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false, 
        },
        backend: {
            backends: [
                HttpBackend, // if you need to check translation files from server
                resourcesToBackend((language, namespace) => import(`../locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`))
            ], // the most important part that allows you to lazy-load translations
            backendOptions: [{
                loadPath: 'http://localhost:4000/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
            }]
        }
    });

export default i18n;
```

Let me know if you need further explanations. Hope the solution helps.